# Php variable precendence

Tags: php

I've one issue about php variable. Let's example:

This is my while loop which i want to edit user contact list.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addcontacts WHERE name LIKE 'a%' AND uname = 
'$uname'");

while($re = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id = (int) $re['id'];  
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['name'])));
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['surename'])));
$group = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['group'])));
$email =  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['email'])));
$skype = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['skypeid']))); 
$facebook = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['facelink']))); 
$twitter = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['twitterlink'])));
$aim = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['aimid'])));
$myspace = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['myspacelink'])));
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['specialnote'])));

more code......
?>
```

So my questions is, Is there anyway to access this **$id** before **$sql** query ? I need this **$id** value to the top of the form because of there are a button name: Edit Contacts. So if i get this **$id** value then i can edit user contact list.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($x)))`. Use the correct escaping for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @well Mark Byers can you please tell me when i used mysql_real_escape_string or htmlspecialchars or trim?

Comment: Too much to write in a comment. I suggest you read the documentation for each method.

Comment: Using m_r_e_s *after* a query doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The ID comes from the database, so you must perform *some* query before you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$id` is the id given from the MySQL record. As far as I understood your question, you would need to do your query before building the form.

You said

> I need this $id value to the top of the form because

So I assume there is a bit of a bad design. You need the form to update a record? If so, you should call the form with the `id` (or id's) of the record given that you want to modify.

Comment: Right you understand that was bad design:)

Comment: @well pduersteler can you please tell me when i used mysql_real_escape_string or htmlspecialchars or trim?

Comment: these are functions for very different situations, I suggest you read about them on php.net. `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes special chars so your mysql queries have a protection against e.g. sql injections. `htmlspecialchars` just converts chars to their according html entity. and trim just removes white spaces.